# Flink Sql Get intermediate results from grouped window aggregation

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I know that flink doesn't support out of the box getting intermediate results of the current window of a group aggregation. The results are emitted only for the windows that are closed by the moving water mark.

However, i was able to write a query to fetch intermediate results the latest window of group aggregation.

```
CREATE VIEW USER_PURCHASES_LATEST_5_DAY_WINDOW
WITH MAX_PURCHASE_TIME as (
  select CAST(max(PURCHASE_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) MAX_PURCHASE_DATE 
  from USER_PURCHASES
) 
SELECT 
  USER_ID,
  PURCHASE_AMOUNT,
  PURCHASE_TIMESTAMP,
  window_start as CURRENT_WINDOW_START,
  window_end as CURRENT_WINDOW_END,
  CAST(window_time as DATE)
 FROM TABLE(
    HOP(
      DATA => TABLE USER_PURCHASES,
      TIMECOL => DESCRIPTOR(PURCHASE_TIMESTAMP),
      SLIDE => INTERVAL '1' DAY,
      SIZE => INTERVAL '5' DAYS))
where CAST(window_time AS DATE)  = (select MAX_PURCHASE_DATE from MAX_PURCHASE_TIME )
```

Then i do aggregations on top of it.

```
SELECT USER_ID,
       SUM(PURCHASE_AMOUNT) PURCHASE_AMOUNT_LAST_5_DAYS,
       COUNT(*) PURCHASE_COUNT_LAST_5_DAYS
FROM USER_PURCHASES_LATEST_5_DAY_WINDOW
GROUP BY USER_ID
```

The output of the final query:

```
|op | user_id | Purchase Amount | Purchase Count |
----- Result after event 1 -----
| +I |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
---- Result after event 2 ----
| -U |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| +U |                              1 |                       3000 |                       2 |
--- Result after of event 3 ---

| -U |                              1 |                       3000 |                       2 |
| +U |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| -D |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| +I |                              2 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| +I |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| -U |                              1 |                       1500 |                       1 |
| +U |                              1 |                       3000 |                       2 |
```

10 Rows returned for 3 events...

What i notice is, this is generating way more CDC records.
Also it is replaying the whole state for every event.

Can someone help me clearly understand what is happening here and why this is a bad approach.

Regards,
Harish.